# Sending cards to $n$ people

Tags: combinatorics

A class contains $100$ people. Each person sends a card to $n$ other people. If we want to be sure that there are two people who sent cards to each other, what is the least number that $n$ could be? How do I solve these kind of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a circle facing forward. Make every person send a letter to the $49$ people in front of them. No two people send letters to each other. Suppose everyone sends $50$ or more letters,then at least $100\cdot50$ letters are sent. We prove a pair of persons must have sent two letters to each other. Assume otherwise, then for each pair of persons at most one letter was sent between them. but then at most $\binom{100}{2}=\frac{100\cdot99}{2}< 100\cdot 50$ letters where sent, a contradiction. Hence the least value for $n$ is $50$.